# Unable to add checkpoint in Great Expectations

Tags: python, great-expectations

This is the code used:

```py
import great_expectations as gx

context = gx.get_context()

validator = context.sources.pandas_default.read_csv(
    'sample.txt'
)

validator.expect_column_values_to_be_between('age',0,100)

checkpoint = context.add_or_update_checkpoint(
    name="my_quickstart_checkpoint",
    validator=validator,
)
```

Last line throws type error.

```
TypeError: add_or_update_checkpoint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'validator'
```

Expectation works fine but not checkpoint creation.

Comment: What version of Great Expectations are you using ?  e.g. ver 0.18.9 expects validations  - a list of dictionaries that describe each validation that is to be executed, including any actions.  Check out this https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/reference/learn/terms/checkpoint#

Answer (score 0):

```
from ruamel import yaml
yaml_config = f"""
name: "<add your checkpoint name>"
class_name: SimpleCheckpoint
validations:
  - batch_request:
      datasource_name: "<add your datasource name>"
      data_asset_name: "<add your data asset name>"
    expectation_suite_name: "<add your expectation suite name>"
"""

context.add_checkpoint(**yaml.load(yaml_config))
checkpoint_result = context.run_checkpoint(checkpoint_name="<add above defined name>")
```